# What does this C++ syntax( template<> struct __nv_tex_rmnf_ret<char> {typedef float type;}; ) statement mean?

Tags: c++

In the CUDA header file, `/usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64/linux/include/texture_fetch_function.h`, there is the following statements:

```
template<typename T> struct __nv_tex_rmnf_ret{};
template<> struct __nv_tex_rmnf_ret<char> {typedef float type;};
```

I understand the first statement is the definition of struct template. But what does the latter mean? I have never seen such C++ syntax before. Could anyony explain it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you confused about the `template<>` syntax for template specialization or the `typedef float type;` syntax for declaring a class member type?

Comment: @Nathna Pierson Sorry for my unclarify. My confuse is about template<> and <char>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`template<>` introduces an *explicit specialization* of a previously declared (primary) template (here the first line). It has otherwise the same syntax as the primary template uses, except that the name in the declarator (here `__nv_tex_rmnf_ret`) is replaced by a template-id (here `__nv_tex_rmnf_ret<char>`) which should be valid for the primary template.

Basically it replaces the definition of the template for the specific specialization determined by the template-id.

`__nv_tex_rmnf_ret<char>` is now a class containing a `typedef` for `type`, but all other specializations `__nv_tex_rmnf_ret<T>` where `T` is not `char` are completely empty classes.

Answer (score -1):

It's called template specialization.

Edit: Removed low-quality link.

Comment: A link is okay so long as your answer actually *contains an answer* and not just a link. I usually run into the opposite situation where someone drops a comment as an answer because they lack the reputation. But you have the reputation and still placed a comment as an answer. I would also recommend not linking to geeks for geeks. It's a hot garbage site.

Comment: Apologies. I got the link from a quick Google search and it looked superficially correct. I figured linking to it wouldn't be more useful than trying to come up with own explanation for a standard C++ topic.